# Automatic Horizontal scroll in Div element in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div html element in my view that contains a 3 sub div elements inside it, and i had designed it to display the sub div elements on the same line (beside each other not under each other) , each sub div element contains some control and each sub div element has a fixed width .

I want to set a button in the page that when user clicks on that button it triggers the horizontal scroll of the main div element and scroll it into certain position.

How should i do this ? . it is better if it could be done using Javascript or Jquery but if there is any other solution it would be Okay.

if there is anything in the question that needs clarification , just tell me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
       .container div {
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}
#two {
  background: yellow;
}
#three {
  background: violet;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 4000px;
}
#button-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 40px;
}
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
        $('body').on('click', 'button', function () {
            var target = '#' + this.id.split('-')[1]
            var offsetLeft = $(target).offset().left
            $('body').animate({
                scrollLeft: offsetLeft
            }, '500');
        })
     
    </script>
    <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />

   
    
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="one">hello</div>
        <div id="two">hello</div>
        <div id="three">hello</div>
    </div>

    <div id="button-container">
        <button id="scroll-one">Scroll to div 1</button>
        <button id="scroll-two">Scroll to div 2</button>
        <button id="scroll-three">Scroll to div 3</button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: show us what have u done and where are you facing the problem so we can take look on it so pl show some codes

Comment: At least, show us your html structure. If possible in a working demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: When you're talking about some behavior occuring when the user does something on the page, you're talking about JavaScript. HTML is static and does nothing on its own after page load. jQuery is a library *written* in JavaScript, to provide an easier API than JavaScript does directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Use `scrollLeft()` to scroll horizontally. Hope it helps

```js
$('body').on('click', 'button', function() {
  var target = '#' + this.id.split('-')[1]
  var offsetLeft = $(target).offset().left
  $('body').animate({
    scrollLeft: offsetLeft
  }, '500');
})
```

```css
.container div {
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}
#two {
  background: yellow;
}
#three {
  background: violet;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 4000px;
}
#button-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="one">hello</div>
  <div id="two">hello</div>
  <div id="three">hello</div>
</div>

<div id="button-container">
  <button id="scroll-one">Scroll to div 1</button>
  <button id="scroll-two">Scroll to div 2</button>
  <button id="scroll-three">Scroll to div 3</button>
</div>
```

**[UPDATE]**

The entire code!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .container div {
      width: 20%;
      height: 200px;
      background: red;
      float: left;
    }
    #two {
      background: yellow;
    }
    #three {
      background: violet;
    }
    .container {
      height: 100%;
      width: 4000px;
    }
    #button-container {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 20px;
      left: 40px;
    }
  </style>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />



</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="one">hello</div>
    <div id="two">hello</div>
    <div id="three">hello</div>
  </div>

  <div id="button-container">
    <button id="scroll-one">Scroll to div 1</button>
    <button id="scroll-two">Scroll to div 2</button>
    <button id="scroll-three">Scroll to div 3</button>
  </div>
  <script>
    $('body').on('click', 'button', function() {
      var target = '#' + this.id.split('-')[1]
      var offsetLeft = $(target).offset().left
      $('body').animate({
        scrollLeft: offsetLeft
      }, '500');
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i coped your code into my page but when i click the buttons nothing happen , i can see it works when i click run code snippet and it exactly what i need to do , may be there is something missed in the code snippet you had wrote ,thanks for your answer

Comment: I just Created and empty HTML page and i had past your code inside it , i will update the question with my code that had past from your solution

Comment: @Laila Place the `<script>` after the `#button-container`

Comment: now the question is already edited with the HTML code , this is exactly the code that i am using , could you tell me why when clicking on the buttons nothing happens ?!!

Comment: @Laila Because the script tag is in the top. The click event wont get binded because there won't be any button tag when the script tag gets interpreted. Try my updated code.

Comment: i set the script tag directly under the style tag but nothing happened , it still doesn't work , i will update the answer now with my updated code according to your update

Comment: @Laila keep the `<script>` tag between `</div>` and  `</body>`

Comment: it doesn't work ,, could you please arrange the code and post it to me or something ,, i had tried all what u said but nothing works

Comment: @Laila I'll do it in the morning!

Comment: plz don't forget i really need it urgently ! . Thanks in advance

Comment: @Laila First thing in the morning 

Comment: @Laila See the **[UPDATE]**